# componentWillReceiveProps does not get latest props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I work with react and redux. I want to store the windowWidth with mapDispatchToProps and read out the values in another component via props. Unfortunately componentWillReceiveProps never gets the latest value but the value of before. What is wrong?

React, redux

container:

```
that.props.selectWidth({windowWidth: windowWidth});
```

component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function () {
    const windowWidth= that.props.selectedWidth.windowWidth;
 }
```

Comment: there aren't enough details to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function () {
    const windowWidth= that.props.selectedWidth.windowWidth;
 }
```

should be

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
    const windowWidth= nextProps.selectedWidth.windowWidth;
 }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

at the run time of the `componentWillReceiveProps` function `this.props` is still the current props, before the update has taken place. So you need to use the `nextProps` argument that can be passed into `componentWillReceiveProps` in order to get what the props will be after the component finishes updating.